# Securely Accessing Sensitive Terraform Outputs for Frontend and Backend Deployment Workflows

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions

I have a Terraform output file (output.tf) that contains sensitive information, such as function app publishing credentials and storage account access keys. I want to securely store and access these outputs for my frontend and backend deployment workflows. My backend is a Python application deployed in a Function App, and my frontend is a static website that hosts a static HTML file.

I considered two approaches:

Github Secrets: I thought about getting the output from the Terraform apply workflow run and setting the GitHub secret via the GitHub API. I can't

Azure Key Vault: I also considered provisioning an Azure Key Vault to store the sensitive outputs. However, I'm not sure how to integrate Azure Key Vault with my GitHub workflows.

Expectations:

I want to find a secure and reliable way to store and access the sensitive outputs from my Terraform output file for both my frontend and backend deployment workflows.

Comment: "Github Secrets: I thought about getting the output from the Terraform apply workflow run and setting the GitHub secret via the GitHub API. I can't" Why can't you? Be specific in your question. This should be possible in theory,  so please include in your question any errors or issues you ran into.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to integrate Azure Key Vault with my GitHub workflows." I would have Terraform write the secret value to Azure [directly](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_secret), when you run `terraform apply` and stop trying to invent some custom workflow around `terraform output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options are valid. Not sure how you tried the approach with Github API, it would be easier to use [Terraform Github provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs)

If you like to use Azure Key Vault it's [possible as well.](https://github.com/Azure/get-keyvault-secrets)

Comment: Thank you! This TF Github provider is exactly what I'm looking for.